# Better way of implementing synchronous and asynchronous behavior in a client code?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, future

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to make `synchronous` and `asynchronous` behavior of my client. In general, how our client will work as below -

Customer will call our client with a `userId` and we will construct a URL from that `userId` and make a HTTP call to that URL and we will get a JSON String back after hitting the URL. And after we get the response back as a JSON String, then we will send that JSON String back to our customer.

So in this case, as I mentioned above, I need to have `synchronous` and `asynchronous` methods, some customer will call `synchronous` method to get the same feature and some will call our `asynchronous` method to get the data back.

So now I am thinking, what is the best way to implement `synchronous` and `asynchronous` feature in a same client code. I know there might be different answers depending on how people implement but as a developer there might be better way of implementing it as the way currently I am doing.

I am still learning so wanted to know better way of doing this by which I can also tell other people that to solve these kind of problems, you need to do it like this.

For now, I have created an interface like this -

```
public interface Client {

        // for synchronous
        public String execute(final String userId);

        // for asynchronous
        public Future<String> executeAsync(final String userId);
}
```

And then I have our `SmartClient` which implements the above `Client` interface. I am not sure whether I should be doing like this or there is a better way of implementing synchronous and asynchronous feature.

Below is my `SmartClient` code and other high level code inside it which I think is sufficient to understand the whole flow.

```
public class SmartClient implements Client {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    // This is for synchronous call
    @Override
    public String execute(String userId) {

        String response = null;
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task(userId));

        try {
            response = future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Terminated!");
        }

        return response;
    }

    // This is for asynchronous call
    @Override
    public Future<String> executeAsync(String userId) {

        // not sure what should I do here as well?

    }
}
```

Below is my simple class which will perform the actual task -

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private final String userId;

    public Task(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;   
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {

        String url = createURL(userId);

        // make a HTTP call to the URL
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String jsonResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(url , String.class);

        return jsonResponse;
    }

    // create a URL
    private String createURL(String userId) {
        String generateURL = somecode;

        return generateURL;
    }
}
```

But I was doing some research and I found out that the better way is -

> Instead of having two methods one is synchronous and other is
>   asynchronous, have one interface method describing the synchronous
>   behavior. Write an implementation for it. And then provide a wrapper
>   class that wraps around the implementation of your interface that
>   basically calls a wrapped object's method while providing the
>   asynchronous behavior.

But somehow I am not able to understand how to accomplish this? Can anyone provide a simple example basis on my example which will help me to understand better how to do that?

I might be able to learn something new with this.

Comment: If you have working code and want suggestions, use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I still don't have full working code as I am just starting with. And I am just trying to understand the overall implementation architecture so that I can understand and start implementing it. My use case is pretty simple, so any high level example basis on that will help me to understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  this

```
@Override
public Future<String> executeAsync(String userId) {
    return executor.submit(new Task(userId));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. And also as per to my other question, how should I go ahead with Synchronous and Asynchronous behavior? Should I have separate method in my Interface? And implementing it like that? And how about my synchronous method?

Comment: Users can call this method that returns the future and block on it. No need for a separate sync method.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares: Thanks for suggestion. Then how would my interface will look like? Can you provide an example basis on above example in the question? It will help me to understand better. And as you said, that feature has to be provided by us, so that it's up to them whether they need to call synchronous or asynchronous methods. So how would I differentiate them and how would they be making a call?

Comment: I think it makes sense to have 2 separate methods, I would also add timeout arg to sync method

Comment: I see, then how would my synchronous method will look like, the way I have it should be like that? Or some better way of doing synchronous and asynchronous behavior. As I am thinking now that there might be some code common for synchronous and asynchronous method. if you were trying to solve this problem, then how would you do it?

Comment: I think imlementation is correct. The common code for both methods is Task class.

Comment: And in the asynchronous method, I don't need to use timeout arguments? Correct, I can just return back the future?

Comment: Just return Future, Future has get with timeout and without

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44082/discussion-between-ssh-and-evgeniy-dorofeev)

Comment: I see.. It might be silly question to ask but I assume my understanding is correct. But still asking.. if somebody ask you to implement asynchronous method, then we should return future back to them? Correct? And customer who is calling can take care of adding further timeouts as needed in there call to our client code?

Comment: Right, customer is free to use Future as he likes